# How can I move an icon from one td to another td

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a icon in the button of table. I want to move this icon to next td on button click. I have no idea how to do it in angular.

```
<table border="1px">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of ways this can be achieved, but the simplest way to do this is just hide the icon in one place and show is in another place.

For EX:

```
<table border="1px" (click)="clicked()">
    <tr>

      <td [ngClass]="{'random': counter == 0}">www</td>
      <td [ngClass]="{'random': counter == 1}">www</td>
      <td [ngClass]="{'random': counter == 2}">www</td>
      <td [ngClass]="{'random': counter == 3}">www</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>yyyyy</td>
        <td>yyyyy</td>
        <td>yyyyy</td>
        <td>yyyyy</td>
    </tr>
</table>

// In your typescript
  counter = 0;
  clicked() {
    this.counter < 4? this.counter++: this.counter = 0;
  }

//In your css
.random {
  background-color: green;
}
```

[You can play here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-govwkz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: for the first tr there are 4 tds. Lets say if first td has class A and on button click this class should be transferred to second td and again click goes to third td until it reach fourth